# RegExp in Xcode: exclude matches from result set?

Tags: regex, xcode

Looking for proper regular expression syntax to use in Xcode’s "Project Find" to get all occurrences of "nslog" but not "//nslog". Can do each search independently but not sure how to "chain" them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The normal way to say “does not follow” with regular expressions is using the `(?<!...)` construct.  So it’s possible that

```
(?<!//)nslog
```

may work.  It depends on which regex flavor the tool you’re using follows, which is something I don’t know.  But it’s been an hour since you asked, and no one else has offered you any answers, so I figure it can’t hurt anything to try.

In case you cannot do lookbehind negations, a pattern that’s guaranteed to work anywhere is

```
[^/][^/]nslog
```

However, that **does not mean** the same thing as the previous pattern!

Instead of saying must not follow two slashes, it instead means there must be two non-slashes previous to that. These are actually different; consider the case of `nslog` occurring at the start of the line. The first pattern would succeed and the second one would fail.

Finally, if slash is used as a pattern delimiter — meaning, it surrounds and quotes the pattern — then you would have to do one of:

1. Select an alternate pattern delimiter; for example, `#(?<!//)nslog#` if you are permitted to select an octothorpe as the quoting delimiter around your pattern.
2. Backwhack any slashes used internally and induce LTS (Leaning Toothpick Syndrome); for example, `(?<!\/\/)nslog`.
3. Use some form of numeric escape, such as `\057` for octal or `\x2F` for hex; for example, `(?<!\x2F\x2F)nslog`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: +1 `(?<!\/\/)nslog` is the correct answer. According to [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/XcodeProjectManagement/150-Searching_Files_and_Projects/searching_files_and_projects.html), XCode uses the ICU library for regular expression searches, and according to [their documentation](http://userguide.icu-project.org/strings/regexp) using [^pattern] doesn't work but the negative look-behind does. Also, it says you must escape the forward slashes with a back slash.

Answer (score 0):

The closest I think you can get is to search for e.g. `[^/]NSLog` - that will find `NSLog` but not `//NSLog`. Of course it will still find `// NSLog`, which may or may not work for you.

Comment: Doesn't work with the [ICU library](http://userguide.icu-project.org/strings/regexp) (which is used in XCode).

Comment: @Drackir: well I did actually test this with Xcode 3.2.3 prior to posting the above answer and it seemed to work OK. What makes you think that it doesn't ? Have you actually tried it ?

Comment: I take my comment back. :P I did test it but I think the cursor must have been below my test lines and it didn't loop to the beginning. Sorry! [^//] works for me, though it is susceptible to what tchrist mentioned below (about not finding them at the beginning of the line).

Comment: @Drackir: no problem - you had me worried for a moment. ;-)