# Use regular expression in Xcode to exclude phrased from find results

Tags: regex, xcode

I need to find in project files all occurrences of `<LIB>` or `<M>` but only if there is no `<TOLERATED>`.

E.g. find all this:

```
// <M> a bit of code
// <LIB> rename with prefix
```

But don't show these:

```
// <M><TOLERATED> a bit of code
// <TOLERATED><LIB> rename with prefix
```

My tries:
This gives you results with both `<LIB>` and `<TOLERATED>`: `<LIB>(.*?)TOL`
Then I've tried to negate the `<TOLERATED>` with: `<LIB>(.*?)(?!TOL)` but that gives me back lines with both `<LIB>` and `<TOLERATED>`

I've tried many other ways to exclude the `<TOLERATED>` from the search results but none of them worked:

```
<LIB>(?!TOL\b)\b\w+
<LIB>(.*?)(?!TOL\b)\b\w+
<LIB>(.*?)(?<!TOLERATED)
<LIB>(.*?)+\b(?<!\bTOLERATED)
```

and many others.

What I've been looking at:
[RegExp in Xcode: exclude matches from result set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4124111/regexp-in-xcode-exclude-matches-from-result-set)

Thanks for your help --Josef

Comment: Try something and let us know how close you got. Then someone may be more inclined to help rather than just write the thing for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
^(?!.*?<TOLERATED>).*?<(?:LIB|M)>
```

Comment: Incredible, it took me 2hrs to fight with it and now you've got it. Thanks!